# Git stuck on master | MERGING

Tags: git

There are two remotes assigned, `origin` is used to pull the changes and `harmeet` is the production.

I tried `git reset --hard` but as soon as I pull latest changes the status reverts to `master | MERGING` and then I can't push latest code to `harmeet` because Git tells me everything is up to date.  I am not sure what is wrong here.

[image: Git Status]

Comment: [`git merge --abort`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_description)

Comment: That gets rid of MERGING but how do I push the latest code to it without pulling from origin? As soon as I pull the MERGING comes back.

Comment: It comes back because you have conflicts (you changed the same files that were changed in remote you are pulling from) you need to resolve.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the case.

Comment: It could also be, that you have to commit. See `git status`. (obviously, this was not the case for you)

Comment: I have the same text (master|MERGING) at my local master. I was trying to merge 2 divergent branches (_both_ contained commit(s) exclusive to only that branch). I did this in a test repo to see what would happen if i merged them. When I tried, I got some sort of wierd vim-looking prompt asking me to input additional info about the merge, but it wouldn't let me type. I closed the bash window in an attempt to abort, but when i reopened, the (master|MERGING) tag was displayed. It was as if it was stuck mid-merge...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in [@Holger's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39878955/git-stuck-on-master-merging#comment67044603_39878955), you can do `git merge --abort` to abort the merge. However, you might not want to do that. The merge happens because the remote (`origin`) has changes that you don't have locally. Your history might look something like this:

```
*--*--A--B--C [master, harmeet/master]
       \
        D--E [origin/master]
```

(Note that `master` == `harmeet/master`. I'll come to that in a minute.)

There are three solutions: merge, rebase, or force update.

### Merge

The easiest solution would be to just complete the merge. To do so, resolve any conflicts in your editor, stage with `git add .`, and commit with `git commit`. Your history would then look like this:

```
*--*--A--B---C [harmeet/master]
       \      \
        \      F [master]
         \    /
          D--E [origin/master]
```

and then you can `git push origin master` to update `origin` and `git push harmeet master` to update `harmeet`.

### Rebase

If you want to keep a linear history, abort the merge and then do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

(If there are any conflicts, resolve them and continue with `git rebase --continue`.)

Your history would then look like this:

```
*--*--A--B--C [harmeet/master]
       \
        D--E [origin/master]
            \
             B'--C' [master]
```

You can then update `origin` with:

```
git push origin master
```

and force-update `harmeet` with:

```
git push --force-with-lease harmeet master
```

Your final history would then be:

```
*--*--A--D--E--B'--C' [master, origin/master, harmeet/master]
```

### Force-update

If you *really* don't want the changes from `origin`, you can do:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

and your history would look like this:

```
*--*--A--B--C [master, harmeet/master, origin/master]
```

---

If Git tells you that `harmeet/master` is up-to-date, then it is at the same commit as your local `master`, unless someone has pushed to `harmeet/master` since your last fetch.

If your goal is to get the changes from `origin` (commits `D` and `E`) to `harmeet`, then you'll need to either rebase or merge, and then push, as described above.

Comment: I had to go with -f push because the way we have our process setup, no commits are to be made to 'origin' after making changes to 'harmeet'. So I did a git add . and then did a force push to 'harmeet' and then did a git pull origin master and then pushed the latest code to 'harmeet'. Great answer, cleared a few additional things for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have detected on one of my colleagues machine `master | MERGING` status happens if developer exists from merge commit description without any input.

At this stage, you will just need to send a commit and describe a description as follows:

```
git commit -m 'merge commit'
```

Other answers are mostly focused on rollback, however if your case to forward, you may use that solution.

Comment: That's it, thanks!
I use Webstorm IDE, i'm not used to git terminal anymore ueheuheueuh.